# meaning of "help"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, definition

The Cambridge Dictionary has the following definition of "help":

> to do something for someone

And the example sentence:

> Dad always helps me with my homework.

I'm wondering this sentence means "Dad always does my homework for me."

Comment: Is that Cambridge's full entry for the word "help"? Are there other definitions? I suspect one of the others is correct

Comment: The Cambridge definition I found reads: _to make it possible or easier for someone to do something, by doing part of the work yourself or by providing advice, money, support, etc._

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E%E7%BE%8E%E5%BC%8F%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/help

Comment: There is no way to know what the sentence means without more context. It could mean "provides assistance" to "does it completely".

Answer (score 1):

The queried sentence could mean anywhere from the father merely providing occasional assistance through the father doing the work with no input from the putative student. Without more there's really no way to tell just how much work the father is performing.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It means that "Dad does something for me, concerning my homework"

What the "something" is isn't defined, but from context and general knowledge it probably includes checking answers, support on harder questions, motivation, giving examples.  It doesn't mean "doing everything for me", only "doing something".